# How to create page scroll link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I link the navigation bar items: home & about to trigger page scroll to page locations: .header & .gallery respectively? Here is full code including .header and .gallery > https://jsfiddle.net/zkxscv95/2/

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="product">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

$(".home").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".header").offset().top},
        'slow');
    });

$(".product").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".gallery").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea that you could use classes for anchor links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is where your `header` and `gallery` names are, give those tags an `id` attribute. Then in your `a` href links for Home and About, just give it the `id` of those attributes. So change

```
 <li><a href="#" class="home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="product">About</a></li>
```

to

```
 <li><a href="#homeLink" class="home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#productLink" class="product">About</a></li>
```

and add attributes to the tags such as:

```
 <div id="homeLink" class="header">
```

and

```
<ul id="productLink" class="gallery">
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L4ofqup3/

Hopefully this helps

Comment: This makes sense and works however how do I indicate that the top of the page needs to stay below the fixed header? do I have to set heights to achieve this or can I avoid that?

Comment: What do you mean the top to stay below the fixed header? Like make the navbar sticky?

Comment: Yes, I added a background color to the navbar to show how it hides content when it jump scrolls to the top of the page here: https://jsfiddle.net/8p19gafm/

Comment: Ah I see. Since this is a different kind of question, please make a new question so this one can be closed. I will be glad to help you on it, as I'm looking into it now, but just make a new question so you can have some other guys try to help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are trying to do should work the way you expect. Try this snippet and see if it demonstrates what you are trying to do. All I did was add some elements which are large enough to force scrollbars to appear. Apologies for the harsh colors.

```js
$(".home").click(function() {
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".header").offset().top},
    'slow');
});

$(".product").click(function() {
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".gallery").offset().top},
    'slow');
});
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 120vh;
}

.gallery {
  background-color: green;
  height: 120vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="product">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="gallery"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **class** attribute for identifying unique names.
Use **id** instead  and refer to element in the code with **#** sign

```
scrollTop: $("#header").offset().top},
```